# Indexes for LINQ queries

Tags: .net, linq, where-clause, indexing

Please advise is there a standard way to make queries like this faster

```
var res = qlist.Where(o => o.left >= x && o.right >= x).ToList()
```

qlist object can contain up to million elements and such query can be very slow. Are there any indexes for linq or something similar?

Thanks

Update:
Sorry cannot answer in comments. 
It is linq-to-objects, the aim is to cache DB.

Comment: Why you have to store milion elements in memory, is this not approriate solution, index should be in database?

Comment: Is this Linq-to-objects? Or any other context like Linq2Sql?

Answer (score 3):

Although LINQ2SQL queries performed against a database enjoy the indexes that may be defined in the database, there are no indexes for LINQ queries performed in memory.

Unfortunately, you would need to roll your own: sort the list, use [`List.BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f90y839.aspx) to get the initial and the last positions, and then use LINQ to get all entries in between.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to cache DB data. List.BinarySearch will not help. Probably I need to write my own R-tree index

Answer (score 3):

Besides of telling you to use database for that (as written already), you can improve performance in two ways:

1. Use AsParallel:

   var res = qlist.AsParallel().Where(o => o.left >= x && o.right >= x).ToList();
2. You can insert your items into two different sorted lists, one by `left` and the other by `right`. For a given x, find the item that equals (or nearly equals) to it with a binary search, and take all items after that item from both lists. The final result should be items that were selected from both lists. I don't know if it is more efficient. It depends how many inserts you do and how much items you'll find.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to cache DB data. List.BinarySearch will not help. Probably I need to write my own R-tree index